# my image is not showing properly loaded from url

Tags: android, url, image-loading

i m loading image from url ...its not displaying first time ...when i again click on same then image is displaying ...can you please help me ...why image is not loading in first time

thanks in advance

```
  ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext(),
                UserByIdProfile.this);


        //

        image.setTag(image_url);
  imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, UserByIdProfile.this, image);
```

here is my image loader class

```
public class ImageLoader {


    // the simplest in-memory cache implementation. This should be replaced with
    // something like SoftReference or BitmapOptions.inPurgeable(since 1.6)
    private HashMap<String, Bitmap> cache = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();

    private File cacheDir;

    static ArrayList<String> img_path = new ArrayList<String>();

    static String sd_card_folder_name = "ImageLoader";

    static int width;
    Context mContext;

    public ImageLoader(Context context, Activity acc) {
        mContext = context;
        // Make the background thead low priority. This way it will not affect
        // the UI performance
        photoLoaderThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 1);

        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        acc.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        Log.d("width", "width = " + width);

        cache.clear();

        img_path = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Find the dir to save cached images
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir = new File(android.os.Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory(), sd_card_folder_name);
        else
            cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
        if (!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();

    }

    final int stub_id = R.drawable.loader;

    public void DisplayImage(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView) {
        try {
            String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());

            File[] file_array = cacheDir.listFiles();

            for (int i = 0; i < file_array.length; i++) {
                img_path.add(file_array[i].getName());
            }

            if (img_path.contains(filename)) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                        .decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/" + sd_card_folder_name + "/"
                                + filename));
            } else {
                if (cache.containsKey(url)) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(cache.get(url));
                } else {
                    queuePhoto(url, activity, imageView, filename);
                    imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView, String _name) {
        // This ImageView may be used for other images before. So there may be
        // some old tasks in the queue. We need to discard them.
        photosQueue.Clean(imageView);
        PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView, _name);
        synchronized (photosQueue.photosToLoad) {
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.push(p);
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.notifyAll();
        }

        // start thread if it's not started yet
        if (photoLoaderThread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW)
            photoLoaderThread.start();
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        // I identify images by hashcode. Not a perfect solution, good for the
        // demo.

        if (url != null && !(url.equals(""))) {
            String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
            File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);

            /*
             * // from SD cache Bitmap b = decodeFile(f); if (b != null) return
             * b;
             */
            // from web
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
                Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
                os.close();
                bitmap = decodeFile(f);
                return bitmap;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    // decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {
            // decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
             final int REQUIRED_SIZE=300;
                int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
                int scale=1;
                while(true){
                    if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                        break;
                    width_tmp/=2;
                    height_tmp/=2;
                    scale*=2;
                }
            // decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public String _name;

        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i, String n) {
            url = u;
            imageView = i;
            _name = n;
        }
    }

    PhotosQueue photosQueue = new PhotosQueue();

    public void stopThread() {
        photoLoaderThread.interrupt();
    }

    // stores list of photos to download
    class PhotosQueue {
        private Stack<PhotoToLoad> photosToLoad = new Stack<PhotoToLoad>();

        // removes all instances of this ImageView
        public void Clean(ImageView image) {
            for (int j = 0; j < photosToLoad.size();) {
                if (photosToLoad.get(j).imageView == image)
                    photosToLoad.remove(j);
                else
                    ++j;
            }
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    // thread waits until there are any images to load in the
                    // queue
                    if (photosQueue.photosToLoad.size() == 0)
                        synchronized (photosQueue.photosToLoad) {
                            photosQueue.photosToLoad.wait();
                        }
                    if (photosQueue.photosToLoad.size() != 0) {
                        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
                        synchronized (photosQueue.photosToLoad) {
                            photoToLoad = photosQueue.photosToLoad.pop();
                        }
                        Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                        cache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                        Object tag = photoToLoad.imageView.getTag();
                        String FileName = photoToLoad._name;
                        if (FileName != null
                                && ((String) FileName).equals(photoToLoad._name)) {
                            BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp,
                                    photoToLoad.imageView, FileName);
                            Activity a = (Activity) photoToLoad.imageView
                                    .getContext();
                            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
                        }
                    }
                    if (Thread.interrupted())
                        break;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // allow thread to exit
            }
        }
    }

    PhotosLoader photoLoaderThread = new PhotosLoader();

    // Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        ImageView imageView;
        String file_name;

        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, ImageView i, String _name) {
            bitmap = b;
            imageView = i;
            file_name = _name;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (bitmap != null) {

                load_full_image(imageView, file_name, bitmap);

            } else
                imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    private Runnable mMyRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        }
    };

    public void load_full_image(ImageView img, String _name, Bitmap btmp) {
        img_path = new ArrayList<String>();

        File[] file_array = cacheDir.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < file_array.length; i++) {
            img_path.add(file_array[i].getName());
        }

        if (img_path.contains(_name)) {
            Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(),BitmapFactory
                                .decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/" + sd_card_folder_name + "/"
                                        + _name));
            //sssss img.setBackground(d);
        } else {

            Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(),btmp);

           // img.setBackground(d);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        // clear memory cache
        cache.clear();

        // clear SD cache
        File[] files = cacheDir.listFiles();
        for (File f : files)
            f.delete();
    }

}
```

Comment: Just visit this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/17917897#17917897 here is my answer given with 4 upvote and use AQuery for this.

Comment: Why It Will BE used ...Explain??????

Comment: Its given by android itself and whatever you are used before is, developed by any individual, so its not perfect at all, but AQuery is a very big thing to use, you can download image, Bitmap and you can call webservices using AQuery as well. Just read about it on google, you will find lots of things about it.

Comment: Please upvote the answer, if you found useful.

Comment: I downloaded Jar File ..And Import
Aquery aq=new Aquesry(this)
aq.id(Imagview).image(url,false false);

not displaying any image

Comment: is your url proper? and make it true, true instead of false, false, and then check your internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

I think you commented img.setBackground.

```
public void load_full_image(ImageView img, String _name, Bitmap btmp) {
    img_path = new ArrayList<String>();

    File[] file_array = cacheDir.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < file_array.length; i++) {
        img_path.add(file_array[i].getName());
    }

    if (img_path.contains(_name)) {
        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(),BitmapFactory
                            .decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/" + sd_card_folder_name + "/"
                                    + _name));
        //sssss img.setBackground(d);  
    } else {

        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(),btmp);

       // img.setBackground(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: ya But mY Problem IS That ...unable To fetch Image First TIme ....SEconde Time I Hit on Url Then It is displaying